# ASP.NET MVC 2 - How to write RouteUrl with Url property in context.MapRoute modified?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, actionlink, absolute-path, maproute

I have an area named User, and I write MapRoute for it:

```
  context.MapRoute(
      "User_Category",
      "User/Category/{categoryId}",
       new { controller = "Product", action = "Category", categoryId = UrlParameter.Optional },
       new { categoryId = @"\d+" }
  );
```

This is other example, I have a link:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Điện thoại", "Category", new { area = "User", controller = "Product", id = 1  }, null) %>
(http://localhost:8578/User/Product/Category/1)
```

Sure, I can't do this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Điện thoại", "User/Category", new { area = "User", controller = "Product", id = 1  }, null) %>
```

Following MapRoute above, it's modified. It means that it's in an Area, I don't know how to pass Area Name into ActionLink to have: `http://localhost:8587/User/Category/1`

But the thing I want is replace ActionLink to RouteUrl to get absolute link like `**http://localhost:8587/User/Category/1**`

***What should I do?*** And how I can remove User Name in Url? Thanks for watching!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your route is defined with the route parameter `categoryId` but your action link uses the parameter just `id`? If so, try this instead:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Điện thoại", "Category", new { area = "User", controller = "Product", categoryId= 1  }, null) %>
```

If you want the full absolute URL then you could do:

```
<a href="<%= Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Url.Action("Category", new { area = "User", controller = "Product", categoryId= 1  }) %>">Điện thoại</a>
```

Comment: @lan Routledge: Thanks! But I gave ActionLink to demonstrate for this, I want to know how to display Link Name ("Điện thoại") in Absolute Link (RouteUrl) include Area Name in there.

Comment: I have changed the answer to include details for an absolute URL

Comment: @lan Routledge: Could I remove Area Name in Area?

Comment: If you are in the same area then yes, you can remove area name.